# How can I reduce the image file size in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i'm using react native with react-native-image-picker

When I load a photo(by using showCameraRoll function), the image size is too large. The size is 4032 x 3024 and the total image size is over 3MB.

But I want to make the size less than 1024 * 1024 and 900KB. What should I do?

this is my code

```
    import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';


    const Upload = ({navigation}) => {
    
      const options = {
        title: 'Load Photo',
        customButtons: [
          {name: 'button_id_1', title: 'CustomButton 1'},
          {name: 'button_id_2', title: 'CustomButton 2'},
        ],
        storageOptions: {
          skipBackup: true,
          path: 'images',
        },
      };


      const showCameraRoll = () => {
        launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
          if (response.error) {
          } else {
            setImageSource(response.uri);
          }
          const form = new FormData();
          form.append('image', {
            name: 'SampleFile.jpg', // Whatever your filename is
            uri: response.uri, //  file:///data/user/0/com.cookingrn/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_5f6898ee-a8d4-48c9-b265-142efb11ec3f.jpg
            type: 'image/jpg', // video/mp4 for videos..or image/png etc...
          });

      };
```

how can i fix my code to reslove this problem?

Comment: `The size is 4032 x 3024 ` You mean the resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-native-image-picker` library has `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` options.

[Options - React Native Image Picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#options)

According to docs of the library, these options are resizing the selected image.

You can also use the `quality` option to reduce the file size.

You can add these options like this:

```js
const options = {
  maxWidth: 1024,
  maxHeight: 1024,
  quality: 0.9,
  title: 'Load Photo',
  customButtons: [
    {name: 'button_id_1', title: 'CustomButton 1'},
    {name: 'button_id_2', title: 'CustomButton 2'},
  ],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};
```

Comment: i revise my question but where should i put your code??

Comment: @jackvolten inside your `options` object